# n complement of a number in hardware

Tags: architecture, numbers, hardware, mips, digits

Do you know an algorithm or a way to find out the complement of a number in base N.?

```
      For example number 001112 which is in base 3 .
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a number with k digits, subtract it from (N<sup>k</sup>)<sub>N</sub> (perform the subtraction in base N, of course).

Answer (score 0):

For the definition of the complement see http://www.enggpedia.com/computer-engineering-encyclopedia/dictionary/dgital-logic-design/1603-complements-types-of-complements-radix-a-diminished-radix-complement.
<del>In your example the complement is 3^6 - 001112(base 3) = (333333+1-001112)(base 3) = (332221+1)(base 3) = 332222.</del>

EDIT:

The comments below are of course right. Sorry for posting such a wrong example. Let me try to reformulate what I wanted to say (and please correct me if I am wrong again):

Your example, expressed in base 3, is:

```
 1000000
- 001112
--------
= 221111
```

The question is if a final 1 should be added.
If one has only unsigned numbers, there is no need to add a 1, but the complement does not have an arithmetic significance.
If one has signed numbers, the complement can be interpreted as a kind of the negative of the original number, but not as the negative itself. An example in base 2:
If `n = 01101`, the *1's complement* of `n` is `10010`. If we add both, the result is of course `11111` which is not zero. Thus, the *1's complement* of `n` is NOT `-n`. But if we add a final 1, we get `00000`, i.e. zero. Therefore the result of building the *1's complement* and adding a 1 is called the *2's complement*, and this CAN be interpreted as `-n`.
I assume the same holds true for any base.

Comment: There are no 3's in base 3.

Comment: yes it is going until 2

Comment: you get the 3^6 and then you dived with 3 to find the number in base 3...